# Which is the fastest way to tell if a Channel<T> is empty?

Tags: c#, performance, .net-6.0, channel, system.threading.channels

I am consuming a [`Channel<object>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1) in an `await foreach` loop, and on each iteration I want to know if the channel is empty. Channels don't have an `IsEmpty` property, so I am seeing two ways to get this information: the [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.count) property and the [`TryPeek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.trypeek) method:

```
await foreach (var item in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
{
    ProcessItem(item);
    if (channel.Reader.Count == 0) DoSomething();
}
```

```
await foreach (var item in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
{
    ProcessItem(item);
    if (!channel.Reader.TryPeek(out _)) DoSomething();
}
```

**My question is:** Which is the most performant way to get the `IsEmpty` information? Is it one of the above, or is it something else?

I should mention that my channel is unbounded, but I am open to switching to a bounded channel ([`Channel.CreateBounded<object>(Int32.MaxValue)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel.createbounded)) in case this would be beneficial performance-wise.

My unbounded channel is configured with the [`SingleReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channeloptions.singlereader) option equal to `false` (the default value).

Another detail that might be important: most of the time the check for emptiness will be negative. The producer of the channel tends to write hundreds of items in frequent bursts. The `DoSomething` method triggers such a burst.

Comment: Both `Count` and `TryPeek` depend on the actual channel implementation and only `TryPeek` seems to be available in all three flavors (Bounded, Unbounded, Single-Reader Unbounded). Where available, `Count` returns the count of the underlying storage (Dequeue or ConcurrentQueue) so performance could vary. Bounded channels take lock before either `Count` or `TryPeek`

Comment: Short version: Only TryPeek will work for all channels so performance doesn't matter. What are you trying to do? The current implementation would perform `DoSomething` only once if there's no pending message then go back to waiting. This is a bit like merging two streams where the first has priority. This isn't exacly an `OnIdle` operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I measured the performance of both approaches, with both unbounded and bounded channels, using a home-made benchmark. Essentially I filled a channel with 1,000 elements, and retrieved the `IsEmpty` information 20,000,000 times in a loop. Here are the results:

```
Platform: .NET 6.0.0-rtm.21522.10
Unbounded.Reader.Count: 1,000
Bounded.Reader.Count:   1,000
LoopsCount:             20,000,000

Unbounded-Count    Duration: 706 msec
Unbounded-TryPeek  Duration: 360 msec
Bounded-Count      Duration: 470 msec
Bounded-TryPeek    Duration: 506 msec
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RkF5lF).

So it seems that for my unbounded channel the `.TryPeek(out _)` is the faster approach. There is no need to switch to a bounded channel. The performance is pretty good regardless though.

It should be noted that in my particular use case, it is possible to obtain the `IsEmpty` information essentially for free, by switching from the `await foreach` loop to a nested `while` loop like this:

```
while (await channel.Reader.WaitToReadAsync())
{
    while (channel.Reader.TryRead(out var item))
    {
        ProcessItem(item);
    }
    DoSomething();
}
```

Each time the inner `while` loop completes, the channel is temporarily empty.

The [`ChannelReader<T>.ReadAllAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readallasync) method is implemented [internally](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3ea30ed321949d238bf97534a2a8cbabf580f238/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/ChannelReader.netcoreapp.cs#L18-L27) with a similar nested `while` loop. So I shouldn't lose anything by replicating the same pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The only real option is `TryPeek` because it's the only method available in all three channel flavors, [Bounded](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/BoundedChannel.cs#L118), [Single-Reader Unbounded](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/SingleConsumerUnboundedChannel.cs#L137) and [multi-reader Unbounded](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/UnboundedChannel.cs#L128). Single-Reader unbounded channels don't have a Count implementation.

Where available, `Count` delegates to the underlying collection's count ([bounded](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/BoundedChannel.cs#L79), [unbounded](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/UnboundedChannel.cs#L61). In a Bounded channel it's a [Dequeue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/BoundedChannel.cs#L25) while in an Unbounded channel it's a [ConcurrentQueue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/UnboundedChannel.cs#L20).

The [ConcurrentQueue.Count](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs#L256) is [very expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382815/concurrentqueue-count-extremely-slow-in-net-core) that has to calculate the available items on the fly and the cheap [IsEmpty](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs#L214) method actually calls `TryPeek`.

```
public bool IsEmpty =>
    // IsEmpty == !TryPeek. We use a "resultUsed:false" peek in order to avoid marking
    // segments as preserved for observation, making IsEmpty a cheaper way than either
    // TryPeek(out T) or Count == 0 to check whether any elements are in the queue.
    !TryPeek(out _, resultUsed: false);
```

For bounded channels, [Count](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/BoundedChannel.cs#L79) returns the Dequeue's Count which is stored in a field. The extra locks around this add a bit of overhead, although nothing like ConcurrentQueue's Count. Locking delays will depend on actual usage. Multiple readers will result in more locking.

```
public override int Count
{
    get
    {
        BoundedChannel<T> parent = _parent;
        lock (parent.SyncObj)
        {
            parent.AssertInvariants();
            return parent._items.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

In conclusion, `TryPeek` is the only option available in all channels and the fastest option in unbounded channels. In bounded channels `Count` may be faster depending on actual usage.

Comment: You posted the comment right after I finished including the relevant snippets in addition to the snippet links