# Is it possible C# Dictionary to return a completly wrong value.

Tags: c#

I have a c# dictionary in a multithreaded environment. I'm using TryGetValue for reading without lock and in the same moment the dictionary is reorganizing.
Is it possible to get a completly different value not related to this key? I mean not just a value that is not up-to-date but a value that is totaly wrong corresponding to a different key.

Comment: Show your work first.

Comment: Multithreaded and without lock? Yes, anything can happen. Count yourself lucky the machine didn't blow up.

Comment: @Corak if it's not a web application, don't ignore app domain isolation etc.

Comment: @Mathematics - I stand by "anything can happen". To quote [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593157/this-is-thread-safe-right/19593297#19593297): "Just take the lock."

Comment: It completely depends on the code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: yes!

Long answer: The dictionary is not thread safe by default. If you need a thread safe one, you can use the `ConcurrentDictionary` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx

Also have a look at the Microsoft reference on thread safe collections https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you back this up? I know that `List` throws an error if the collection is modified while iterating it - are you sure that Dictionary doesn't do anything similar?

Comment: @Default The behavior you are describing does happen for `List` as well as for `Dictionary` but it is not directly related to the thread safe access - these are two different things which "may" end up in the same error/exception. But I understood Dim_Ka's question in a more general way